# Crystal Syntax - "Extract" Part of a String Within a String

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports

I am doing this in i-net Designer (another Crystal Report type program).
My problem has two parts...

I am trying to "extract" part of a string from a string. The string that I need will always be in the middle of the main string. But will NEVER be in the same position. The Description and length will always change.

Below is an example.
**Description (this is the main string I am "extracting" from):**

```
    The Name of my Book Here CD CTN1234-5678-9 2-1 CD Carton
```

**Part 1**
The string I am trying to extract is the Part#, **CTN1234-5678-9**. This will always be 14 characters long(3 letters, 9 numbers and 2 dashes).

**Part 2**
I need the description portion only. This is the title of the book starting from the LEFT up to the Part#(CTN1234-5678-9). So I would need only  **The Name of my Book Here CD**

Doing this in "Formula Editor" for my formula fields @PartNumber and @Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a simpler way- but this works:

```
local stringVar myString   := 'The Name of my Book Here CD CTN1234-5678-9 2-1 CD Carton';
local numberVar myPosition := len(myString);

while not(mid(myString, myPosition - 14, 14) like '???????-????-?') and myPosition > 14
 do myPosition := myPosition - 1;

mid(myString, myPosition - 14, 14);
```

Comment: You are awesome man, I got this to work for my PartNumber formula field, I will have to actually look at it to understand how it actually works. Do you have a way to get Part 2? I would appreciate it A LOT.

Comment: I actually went through the sample code you provided and I understand how it worked after going through two different descriptions. Great job! Couldn't get any simpler IMO (but I'm just learning lol).

Answer (score 0):

For **Part 2 - Description** I came up with this (just modifying the last line of code):
Thanks again @Lee Tickett
Appreciate your help!

```
local stringVar myString := 'The Name of my Book Here CD CTN1234-5678-9 2-1 CD Carton';
local numberVar myPosition := length(myString);

while not(mid(myString, myPosition - 14, 14) like '???????-????-?') and myPosition > 14
 do myPosition := myPosition - 1;

uppercase(trim(left(myString, myPosition - 15)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
// {@Book Title}
// ([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1}) - matches the part #
// (.*?) - a non-greedy captured group
// (?= ) - a look-ahead
RegexMatch( "(.*?)(?=([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1}))" )
```

You'll need the [Crystal Reports Regex Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cruflregex/develop/).